# Update Oracle Linux 7 to 8

Tags: oracle-linux

Running Oracle Linux v7.9 at the moment, is there a way to upgrade to Oracle Linux v8.3 (or any v8.x) as an in place upgrade *WITHOUT* installing from a fresh VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Oracle Linux is actually based on RHEL, the answer will be : NO, you cannot upgrade from version 7 to version 8 safely. The differences are just too much.

If you were on RHEL 6, there is (or perhaps, WAS) an package, which does exactly this - prepares the system and upgrades it to the next major version.

But it got pulled out, due to issues with the success rate. Seems like people were often left with broken systems.

EDIT: As per @Tanz87, as of 31 March 2011 (2 months after i made this answer), Oracle is now providing a way to upgrade from Oracle Linux 7 to Oracle Linux 8.3.

Comment: Seems like upgrades from Oracle Linux 7 to 8.3 or above are supported with `leapp`. https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/leapp/

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/leapp/leapp-UpgradingtheSystem.html

```
sudo yum install -y leapp-upgrade --enablerepo ol7_leapp,ol7_latest
sudo sudo leapp preupgrade --oraclelinux
sudo less /var/log/leapp/answerfile
sudo leapp answer --section remove_pam_pkcs11_module_check.confirm=True
sudo less /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt
sudo leapp preupgrade --oraclelinux
sudo leapp upgrade --oraclelinux
```